# How to design a no-load detection circuit and auto cutoff if load is not presented?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, load, detection

How to design a no-load detection circuit, I couldn’t find a reference design,

Is this possible task to perform?

Load is an LED setup, 150V DC, 30mA

If load is not connected to the circuit, power path to the output port should be cutoff,

But when load is connected circuit should automatically release the power to the load.

Circuit should contain small number of components as well.

Comment: You cannot directly sense a 150V LED string without supplying dangerous voltages. Are you allowed to add a third connection on which you can sense a small resistance (like 1K, or even a microcontroller) by applying 5V or less?

Comment: @Brian Drummond  yes that can be allowed

Comment: @Brian Drummond are you recommending to use low voltage path with a resistor (R=10k so low current consumption) on the load? so if current measured in that resistor load shall be detected before powering the high voltage to the actual load?

Comment: I recommend decoupling the problem of detection from the problem of handling unsafe voltages. Your suggestion is a possible way to approach this.